# Google SignIn on Android - Log out does not work since not logged in

Tags: java, android, authentication, google-signin

I have integrated Google SignIn via this guide (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating).

I've done setup like this:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken(AppActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.server_client_id))
            .build();

GoogleSignIn.googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
```

Sign in works with the following code and works perfectly fine:

```
public static void loginGoogleSDK()
{
    Intent signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleApiClient);
    GameApplication.getActivity().startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN);
}
```

The SignIn-Overlay appears, I choose an account and log in. Everything works fine.

Then I try to call logout with the following code after this guide (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/disconnect), but I always the the error message: **Cannot log out, since not logged in**.

```
Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(
        new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(Status status) {
                System.out.println("Google SDK Sign Out Access Status:" + status);
            }
        });
```

The weird part is, that if I call login again, it is automatically successful and I can not choose an account again. Hence, the login is still active and I can not log out.

Comment: The [Add Sign In guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) uses `enableAutoManage` which means they don't need to manually call `googleApiClient.connect()` - where do you call it as it seems you aren't using `enableAutoManage`?

Comment: Argh, yeah. I'm using Cocos2d-x and it's not using Fragment Activity. What do I have to do to make it work without automanage? Where did you find the info for it? I didn't see it anyhwere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [enableAutoManage documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient.Builder.html#enableAutoManage(android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity,%20com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener)), including it:

> Enables automatic lifecycle management in a support library FragmentActivity that connects the client in `onStart()` and disconnects it in `onStop()`.
>
> It handles user recoverable errors appropriately and calls `onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult)` on the `unresolvedConnectionFailedListener` if the `ConnectionResult` has no resolution. This eliminates most of the boiler plate associated with using `GoogleApiClient`.

By not including `enableAutoManage()` like the [Add Sign In guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/sign-in) does, your `GoogleApiClient` never actually connects, causing the error you are experiencing.

If you don't want to use `enableAutoManage()`, you can follow the instructions to [manually manage connections](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client#manually_managed_connections) including providing an implementation for `ConnectionCallbacks` and `OnConnectionFailedListener`.

Comment: Fixed, Thank you a lot. I didn't find this article in the documentation. Following it fixed everything. I couldn't use autoManage indeed, so I implemented the manual way now.